# How to get azure account by app name or client id and secret id?

Tags: azure-active-directory, outlook-restapi

How to find out which account was used to register outlook app in azure?

I have app name, creation date, api client id and and api secret id but cannot find account which was used to register the app to be able to manage it.

It's production app with thousands of users connected so disconnecting all users and creating new one is the last option...

Answer (score 0):

You can login in azure portal by using any user account which belongs to your AD.

Go to **Azure Active Directory**->**App registrations**->find your application by using app name or client id->click **Owners** under **Manage** part->you will find the owner of the application.

[image]

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the idea, but in my azure accounts I cannot search for apps which are not mine apparently...

Comment: @jokuja Did you check 'All applications'? See the screenshot in the updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the update, but my account does not have option "All applications" https://ibb.co/tYMmkZs

Comment: @jokuja Is your active directory the correct one to register the application? It seems that there is no applications registered under your directory.

Comment: yes there is no applications registered, its new empty account created, i have nothing on AD neither our company does

Comment: I created 3 different accounts and always getting just errors when going to any settings: https://ibb.co/QCsL1Vf

Comment: @jokuja Where did you register your outlook app?

Comment: That's what I do not know, I filled in some required data during registration, probably including some company data - but there was no other account associated with it. All I know is app name, client id and secret id.

Comment: @jokuja You can use a account which can use your app to login in azure portal and check the directories.

Comment: I am not able to search directories in Azure, it just throws errors. Same on multiple new accounts.

Comment: I gave up temporarily with the hope that I will never need to change the app settings. But any hint or help would be still awesome!